# Checking all elements of a sublist are equal to another for nubBy

Tags: haskell

So, I want to use `nubBy` to remove all duplicates from a list of lists. In this case `[1,2,3]==[1,3,2]==[2,3,1]` etc, so I'm figuring I need to use `all` and `elem` to ask if all the elements are elements of another list, but I'm struggling to work out the syntax.

To be clear, I have for example

```
[[1,2],[2,3],[4,5],[2,1],[2,3]]
```

and I want to remove duplicates to get the output

```
[[1,2],[2,3],[4,5]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care that the order of the elements in the inner lists of the result match one of the original ones, you can just use `map sort` to sort them before using `nub`. Otherwise, `` nubBy ((==) `on` sort) `` will do the job at the extra cost of sorting the inner lists for each comparison.

Comment: Thanks, though your first sentence doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @npfedwards: I mean, if you have `[[3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 3]]`, does it matter if the result is `[[1, 2, 3]]` since `[1, 2, 3]` did not appear in that order in the original list?

Comment: No it doesn't matter. I just need to get rid of duplicates. How expensive will `map sort` be?

Comment: @npfedwards: It'll be relatively cheap compared to `nub`. To improve on that, you can use `nubOrd = map head . group . sort` for the outer list after sorting the inner one. Also, consider using `Data.Set` or `Data.IntSet` instead of lists.

Comment: @hammar: The reason he does not understand your first sentence is because you accidentally a word, rendering it grammatically nonsensical. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to sort (here, nubBy) by an expensive binary operation is *decorate-process-undecorate* idiom (aka the [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)):

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function

g xs = map snd . nubBy ((==)`on`fst) $ [ (sort ys,ys) | ys <- xs]
```